# web site built using jquerymobile does not open on BB5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple start up page for my website that uses a listview with 2 items (no images) and when I try to launch it from BB5 it takes for ever and shows a white screen. should I do something specific to address BB5? Thanks

### Update

```
<div data-role="page" id="MainPg">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset = true data-dividertheme="a" data-theme="b">
            <li data-role="list-divider">OPTIONS:</li>
            <li><a href="link1.aspx" data-ajax=false >Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Link2.aspx" data-ajax=false >Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using. If you are using a jQuery Core other than 1.6.4 then that could be the issue.

Comment: I use jquery 1.7.1
Here is the body:
 <div data-role="page" id="MainPg">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview"  data-inset = true data-dividertheme="a" data-theme="b">
            <li data-role="list-divider">OPTIONS:</li>
                <li><a href="link1.aspx" data-ajax=false >Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="Link2.aspx" data-ajax=false >Link2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery Core 1.7.1. I had this same issue (nothing but a white-screen on BB5, not sure about BB6) and I fixed it by using the jQuery Core 1.6.4 (the one packaged with jQuery Mobile).

Here is what jQuery recommends on using (for reasons like this issue):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. That helped. I can see the page render on the BB5.but icons dont show. there is just a blank hold or square in place of arrow for the list items, close for select menu, etc.

Comment: actually the blank images show on the simulator but they look fine on the actual device. Thanks

Comment: @user1186390 I noticed you haven't accepted any answers on Stack Overflow yet. If you found any of the answers to your questions to fix your problem(s) then it's common practice to accept the answer by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. Also, if you found an answer helpful (even if it didn't answer your question fully), you can up-vote that answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the final answer is to switch to jquery 1.6.4 and that works.